# How to edit current viewed page html source using Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to build a chrome extension that hides a specific div (with id) from page on load.

I want to know how to edit the source?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery, and write this code in your content script:

```
$("#you_div_id").hide();
```

It's so easy：）

Comment: will this work if I wanted to hide a specific div from the FB page when visiting facebook for example?

Comment: yes. and, any website. btw, if you just want to hide some div. the adblocker extension is a good stuff for you. just search it in google web store. It's free, and awsome.